# Checking empty texboxes and display messagebox

Tags: c#, validation

For my homework I am to ask user for: Name and date of birth (Month, day, year as their own textboxes). Then calculate their age. I must also display an error if the input is incorrect such as empty fields, and incorrect days for the month (for example the month field shouldnt be 0 or more than 12). I have a basic test of: if (dayTextBox.Text > 31 || dayTextBox.Text < 0) then it will change the output to Invalid day. The error message when nothing is entered and the Execute button is clicked is: Input string was not in a correct format. I tried Parse for the variables that will go into the DateTime and that did not work. Also if the month entered is 0 I get: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable Date Time.

I had been using a label to display the errors. This works. However, when Im checking for empty or null fields the program crashes. Without the checking of empty fields the program worked just fine without crashing. I have tried to put this if check above the other checks ( They are all in a if, if else series of statements) as well as before the variables that put each of the fields that change the TextBox.Text(s) into DateTime format to calculate the age.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameOutputLabel.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MonthDOBTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(DayDOBTextBox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(YearDOBTextbox.Text))
        {
            AgeOutputLabel.Text = "Cannot have empty fields";
        }
```

---

for reference here is an example my other checks

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            AgeOutputLabel.Text = "Invalid month. Must be between 1 and 12";
        }
```

This is how my DateTime is set up:

```
 int year = Convert.ToInt32(YearDOBTextbox.Text);
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(MonthDOBTextBox.Text);
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(DayDOBTextBox.Text);
        // This sets the calculation for determining the age
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime usersBirthDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        int age = currentDate.Year - usersBirthDate.Year;
```

Would just like to check for empty and null fields, alongside the checks of the correct input of day, month, year. All while displaying a correct error ( Fields cannot be empty || Month must be between 1 and 12, etc)

Comment: If your program crashes then you should have an error message that explains what is the problem. Could you [edit] your question and add this message?

Comment: Maybe you want to cancel the further operation if it didn't pass the check? You could try to add `return;` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I was not doing the check to see if the TextBoxes were null outside/ before the assignment of the year, month, day variables and that was the reason for the Invalid input. As well as the checks for the year, month, day containing the correct number range, that was also not being done after the assignment of the variables, but before the calculation. It was mostly a matter of order and correct encapsulation of if statements.